# CSS align submenu to parents element

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML snippet for my menu bar:

```css
#menubar {
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

#menubar ul li a.menubutton {
  display: none;
  /* dont show burger symbol (mobile menu symbol) */
}

#menubar ul {
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  /* restrict burger symbol */
  padding: 0.9em;
}

#menubar ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#menubar ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  display: block;
  background: #2F2C2C;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Navigation */

nav {
  display: block;
  height: 2.5em;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0em 0.188em 0em 0.188em;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #454040;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0.563em 0.938em 0.375em 0.983em;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  /* nice transition effect */
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #DBD9D8;
  border-bottom: 0.188em solid #FF0000;
}

nav ul li a.active {
  border-bottom: 0.188em solid #E7590B;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul.submenu {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #DBD9D8;
  border-bottom: 0.188em solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./index.html" class="active">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="./meetings.html">Termine</a></li>
    <li><a href="./organisation.html">Organisation</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="./organisation/page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="./organisation/page2.html">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="./organisation/page3.html">Page3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./about.html">About</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="./about/page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="./about/page2.html">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="./about/page3.html">Page3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The `ul #submenu` are displayed on hover.

I managed to center the submenus with the whole page using `left: 40%` in the `nav ul li:hover ul.submenu` rule. However, I want to position the submenus centered to their parent components, so taking organisation for example I'd like to have the page 2 submenu centered with the parents organisation field and for about the same.

How can I achieve to center relatively to the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the menu entries which have a submenu (i.e. to the `nav ul li` selector)  and change `position: fixed`  to `position: absolute` for the submenu, i.e. the `nav ul li:hover ul.submenu` selector.

This makes the submenu position "relative" to their parent (the main menu entry), so you should then adjust the `left` and `top` settings in the submenu CSS rule accordingly.

```css
#menubar {
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

#menubar ul li a.menubutton {
  display: none;
  /* dont show burger symbol (mobile menu symbol) */
}

#menubar ul {
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  /* restrict burger symbol */
  padding: 0.9em;
}

#menubar ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#menubar ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  display: block;
  background: #2F2C2C;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Navigation */

nav {
  display: block;
  height: 2.5em;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0em 0.188em 0em 0.188em;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #454040;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0.563em 0.938em 0.375em 0.983em;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  /* nice transition effect */
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #DBD9D8;
  border-bottom: 0.188em solid #FF0000;
}

nav ul li a.active {
  border-bottom: 0.188em solid #E7590B;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul.submenu {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -50%;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #DBD9D8;
  border-bottom: 0.188em solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./index.html" class="active">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="./meetings.html">Termine</a></li>
    <li><a href="./organisation.html">Organisation</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="./organisation/page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="./organisation/page2.html">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="./organisation/page3.html">Page3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./about.html">About</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="./about/page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="./about/page2.html">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="./about/page3.html">Page3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment, but the left in the submenu rule seems not to be working, it sticks either to the left or right edge of the site. if i remove the left rule, it gets centered again to the whole site :/

Comment: sounds like you forgot something... Essential are `position: relative` for the `li`elements of the main menu and `position: absolute` for their children `ul` elements. And don't forget to erase the `position: fixed` you had in there before. (You can see that it works in my snippet, which is only a slight modification of your previous code)

Comment: no, just copied your part into mine and still the same behaviour and i am pretty sure there is no other rule interfering

Comment: Well, if you just *copied* it, you didn't erase/change the `position: fixed` I mentioned

Comment: just checked and searched for fixed in the css, the only fixed is in my footer session

Comment: did you remove the `margin-left` you had before?

Comment: I am very sorry, i had the old rules in the css for the content of the index (idk why...). is it possible to have the submenus aligned left to right?

Comment: theoretically yes, if you add `display: inline-block` to these `li` elements. But you would also have to add a *fixed* width to the absolutely positioned `ul` submenus, which won't be the same for all submenus and therefore won't work well.

Comment: so theres no way of a solid working inline version thats centered to its parent component?

Comment: you'd have to define a fixed width separately for each submenu `ul` so that all its `li` items fit into it - then you can position that block as you need

Comment: that sounds not that well. is there any possibility (with your solution) to get the submenu over the content of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just read your question. So you will have to implement this with your own class names. But this is how to centre your child elements inside their respective parents.

```
.child-class{
  width:max-content;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

In order for this to work you have to have a width. This will auto centre align your div or whatever tag you are using.

I recommend this method over position relative, because what's really convenient about using this method is that it will centre align your content evenly even if the different li tags are different widths. Which is convenient for mobile optimisation. :)